# Am I entitled to two compensations?

Tags: eu, cancellations, compensation, delays, klm

I had a two leg flight a few days ago. The flight was cancelled due to "operational issues", and I was automatically booked onto a new flight the day after. So, the delay to the final destination was about 24 hours. I'm pretty sure I'm entitled to a compensation for that.

The flight was from Paris (CDG) via Amsterdam (AMS) to Kristiansand (KRS) with KLM.

The next day, just before boarding, the flight got delayed (CDG to AMS). I was unable to get on the next plane (AMS to KRS) due to this, so I had to wait for 5 hours in transit for the next plane (AMS to KRS). I was automatically booked onto that next flight.

Am I entitled to two compensations, (1) one for the first cancellation and (2) one for the delay?

Comment: What are the compensation amounts you are trying to get?

Answer (score 22):

> Am I entitled to two compensations, (1) one for the first cancellation and (2) one for the delay?

Most likely: yes. The law ([link](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX%3A32004R0261)) is somewhat vague on the topic so this will have to be decided in court. Turns out someone already tried that in court for a very similar case and actually won double compensation ([link](https://www.twobirds.com/en/insights/2020/global/double-compensation-for-cancellation-and-delay-of-subsequent-re-routing-under-regulation-2612004#:%7E:text=The%20CJEU%27s%20interpretation%20of%20Regulation,under%20Article%208%20is%20efficient.))

This being said: the airline is very likely to reject your claim especially since it's not cut and dry. You will have to figure out a strategy to collect it which most likely will involve a 3rd party EU 261 collector, a suitable oversight government agency, a small claims court, full court case, etc.

If it shows up in front of a judge you have a good chance of winning since there is a clear precedent. However, they will not make this easy for you.